# How to find a textbox id in a dynamic table?

Tags: c#

```
var table = "MainContent_Criteria" + criteriaId;
                var row = "MainContent_Row" + criteriaId + +questionId;
                var cell = "MainContent_Cell" +questionId;
                var txt = "MainContent_txt" + questionId;
                //txt = text;
                var myResult1 = FindControl(table).FindControl(row).FindControl(cell).FindControl(txt) as TextBox;
```

I get the exception "**Object reference not set to an instance of an object**" I want to set a value in that textbox.

Comment: Split up the line into sperate Statements and see, what FindControl() returns the null-object. :)

Comment: I just checked the findcontroller seperately but all FindControl() returns null